# How can one learn to visualize 4 dimensional spacetime?

Tags: education, spacetime-dimensions, perception, visualization

I was watching Professor Leonard Susskind's lecture on Quantum Entanglements and he said that there are physicists and people who study physics, who 'rewire' themselves so they can visualize 4 dimensional spacetime in their heads. How can I learn to do this?

Comment: Grab a textbook and solve a lot of special relativity problems, especially the ones that involve graphing.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70897/2451 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20469/2451

Comment: [This PDF](http://www.rpi.edu/dept/phys/courses/Astronomy/CurvedSpacetimeAJP.pdf) might be useful.

Comment: You may want to try learning about Penrose diagrams; these provide a pictorial representation of space-time, and feature its causal structure.

Answer (score 1):

I read the first paragraph of the PDF recommended by Glen The Udderboat, and didn't understand it.  Here's the simple method that I use: drop one of the three space dimensions and replace it with the time dimension.  Use the intuitive three-dimensional visualisation that you've used all your life, and swap space dimensions in and out if you really need to consider three spatial dimensions.